# simplemodal embedded elements don't get focus from keyboard

Tags: javascript, focus, simplemodal

My .aspx's simple simplemodal  contains a single asp:button to postback. Mouse over, and it reacts. Click, and it works. Hit ESC and the dialog closes.

But I can't tab to that close button. I added a straight input button and a textbox to the modal  and they don't get the focus either. Can't get the focus there in onShow code either. So the dialog can't be used solely with the keyboard. Not acceptable.

How is it possible with SimpleModal to make focus non-functional? And how to I make focus work again?

(jQuery 1.9.1, SM 1.4.4, Windoze 7, IE8 (Yeah, I agree...organization standard))

Comment: thanks for the info, what's your question?

Comment: Can't tab to the close button. No elements will get the focus by tabbing to them. None of the controls are reachable from the keyboard.